# MySQL - Update Column if all rows are equal

Tags: php, mysql

I have `N` Rows with same `SlNo` but different `RowNo` as shown below
for eg:

```
SlNo  RowNo  Status
 1     1     Opened
 1     2     Closed
 1     3     Opened
 1     4     Closed
 1     5     Opened
```

If all the Status Column Rows are `Closed` , I want to return `1`.

else `o`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it following:

```
SELECT STATUS FROM `table_1` where SLNO = 1 group by status
```

If you get only one record with value "Closed" then execute the next query

```
UPDATE `table_2` SET Ref_Status = 'Closed' WHERE SLNO = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `my_table` set Status='Closed' where SlNo = 1

Comment: Read the question carefully

Answer (score 0):

Find the count of all rows and check it with the count of `Closed` values.

**Query**

```
select t.`SlNo`,
case when t.`RowNo_Count` = t.`closed_count` then 1 else 0 end as `new_col` 
from(
    select `SlNo`, 
    count(`RowNo`) as `RowNo_Count`,
    sum(case `Status` when 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as `closed_count`
    from `your_table_name`
    group by `SlNo`
)t;
```